# Python: How to export subset of a dataframe to a new dataframe if row number equals to 4i+2, int i = 0, i < len(col), i++

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, export, subset

Here is my dataframe. I want to export all column in row number 2,6,10,14,18,... to a new dataframe
[image]

Here is part of my code

[image]

Comment: Please post all of your code and data as text, not as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `df.loc[rows, columns]`to get certain cells you need.

```
df_new = df.loc[((df.index.values-2)%4) == 0, :]
```